# How do I have a background image for each axis

Tags: 3d-view

Sorry if that's not the exact terms, I'm kinda new here.

My goal is to make this kind of background where you can have one image per axis. I used to know it (these images are from one of my project) but I totally forgot and can't find the solution again.

[image: Background1]
[image: Background2]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I use Blender 2.76.

I found the solution:

1. Press <kbd>N</kbd> (*View -> Properties*)
2. If the new window is all empty, scroll up
3. Check *Background Images*
4. Click on *Add Image*
5. Select your image and select the axis you want

Then repeat steps 4 and 5 for each axis you need to have a background on.

Answer (score 3):

You create a single background image by creating an *Empty -> Image -> Background*:

[image: Menu for creating a background image]

Once selected, the file browser will pop up allowing you to select that image.

By default, the image is created perpendicular to your view, so to create three background images that match the axis,

1. Pick a viewpoint from *Top*, *Front*, or *Left*
2. Use the add menu to create the image empty.

Repeat this for each viewpoint. For each view, if you want the image only visible from that view, go to the Image properties in the property editor and select *Orthographic* and *Only Axis Aligned*:

[image: Image properties orthographic and only axis aligned selected]

It is typical to move the images along their axis so that they are behind the objects you are editing when they are in view.